# Example of Reading User's Email Using Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm creating a C# .Net Core 2.0 console application to read a specific user's email.  I successfully got this [sample console application](https://github.com/MIchaelMainer/GraphNetCore2) working.  So authentication is working.  I added permissions to Read all User's email.  I looked at the API docs and I can't see examples of reading a user's email. Plenty of send examples.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to get every one's mail or just the specific user's mail?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for posting.  I got this to work if I comment out the Filter:

```
            GraphServiceClient client = GetAuthenticatedClient();

            string subject = "RE: ACTION NEEDED:";
            string dt = "2018-10-5T00:00:00";
            IUserMessagesCollectionPage msgs = client.Users["UserName@CompanyName.com"].Messages.Request()
                //.Filter($"receivedDateTime ge '{dt}'")  // Invalid filter
                .Filter($"startswith(subject, '{subject}') and receivedDateTime gt {dt}")
                .Select(m => new { m.Subject, m.ReceivedDateTime, m.From, m.Body })
                .Top(100)
                .GetAsync().Result;
            int msgCnt = msgs.Count;
```

I posted something about getting filter to work.  startswith works but the date filter fails.

Answer (score 0):

To get each one's mail.

```
var users = graphClient.Users.Request().GetAsync().Result;
```

To get the specific user's mail:

```
List<QueryOption> options = new List<QueryOption>
{
     new QueryOption("$filter", "startswith(displayName,'the specific user's mail')")
};
var users= await graphClient.Users.Request(options).GetAsync();
//Or
  var users = await graphClient.Users.Request().Filter("startswith(displayName,'help')").GetAsync();
```

Get Mail:

```
  foreach (var item in users)
    {
      string currentMail=item.Mail;
    }
```

Update 2018-10-7
For your updated post:

You can use the following API to filter the mails:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/inbox/messages?$filter=ReceivedDateTime ge 2018-10-04 and startswith(subject,'{subject}')
```

Comment: It is normal behavior. Many thing is still not supported in Graph API.

Comment: How do you call Web API from graphClient?